# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type' in argparse

Tags: python, parsing, argparse

Hey so I'm using argparse to try and generate a quarterly report. This is what the code looks like:

```
parser  = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-q', "--quarter",  action='store_true', type=int, help="Enter a Quarter number: 1,2,3, or 4 ")
parser.add_argument('-y', "--year", action='store_true',type=str,help="Enter a year in the format YYYY ")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

the error I receive is:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'

as far as I can tell from the argparse documentation type is one of the parameters of the add_argument function. I tried removing this and updating the code to :

```
parser  = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-q', "--quarter",  action='store_true', help="Enter a Quarter number: 1,2,3, or 4 ")
parser.add_argument('-y', "--year", action='store_true',help="Enter a year in the format YYYY ")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I then tried to run it with: `python scriptname.py -q 1 -y 2015` and it is giving me the following error:

> error:unrecognized arguments: 1 2015

I don't know why that is either. Can anyone please shed some light on this.

Comment: Please reformat that code, it's hard to read - 4 chars before each line will make it be a code block.

Comment: Why are you using `action='store_true'`? What was your understanding of what that would do?

Comment: later on in the code i do a check to see if the variables stored in argparse are true. if they are i execute some code.

Comment: if args.quarter and args.year:

Comment: The purpose of `store_true` is to save the value `True` for the named variable.  Specifying a `type` value for the same option is meaningless, and disallowed.

Answer (score 67):

What `action="store_true"` means is that if the argument is given on the command line then a `True` value should be stored in the parser. What you actually want is to store the given year (as a string) and quarter (as an int).

```
parser  = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-q', "--quarter", type=int, help="Enter a Quarter number: 1,2,3, or 4 ")
parser.add_argument('-y', "--year", type=str, help="Enter a year in the format YYYY ")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When you specify `action='store_true` argparse is internally instantiating a `_StoreAction` instance whose constructor does not accept a `type` parameter (since it will always be a boolean (True/False)). You cannot supply `action="store_true"` and 'type' at the same time.

Comment: dang tutorial. They make it look like you need `action="store_true"` if you want a short version like `-q`

Answer (score 19):

The `argparse` documentation is not as detailed as it could be (but still has more information than many users can absorb).

In particular, the actual information that an argument needs varies with `action`.

```
parser.add_argument('-q', "--quarter",  action='store_true', type=int, help="Enter a Quarter number: 1,2,3, or 4 ")
```

A `store_true` action does not take any parameters (i.e. nargs=0).  It's default value is `False`, and if used the attribute is set to `True`.

If you want the user to give one of those four numbers I'd suggest using

```
parser.add_argument('-q', '--quarter', type=int, choices=[1,2,3,4], help="...")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices has a similar example.

The examples in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action give a pretty good idea of what parameters each action class takes.

There is a Python bug/issue discussing improving either the documentation, or the error message when unnecessary parameters are given in the function.  As it stands, it's the Python subclass definition that is issuing the error message.

Comment: Interesting, to so the "optionality" flavor is built in, no need to do `nargs='?'` for example, which apparently conflicts with that built in/default design.

Comment: The base `Action` class has 2 parameters and 8 keyword parameters.  But for the 'store_true' subclass, `_StoreTrueAction` subclass, only 3 of those keywords are in its `__init__`, and only the `help` makes sense.  Class inheritance gives a lot of flexibility, but sometimes makes accurate documentation difficult.

Comment: `argparse` docs on `required` may help https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required

Comment: Got confused when getting this error, turns out when using `action='store_true'`, `type=` is not needed and will cause error. Simply removing it solves the problem.

Comment: Awesome! That suggestion was perfect for what I was going for. I *was* going to have two mutually exclusive arguments that I wanted to store constants (one would be 3 the other 4) but it wouldn't let me use type=int. The 'official' answer tells me why that doesn't work, but your answer showed me a much better way to do what I *really* wanted: provide a selection of exclusive version numbers. And this is easier to expand to support a version 5 (of my script) if it ever comes out. Brilliant!

Comment: I came here to understand the same error I received as OP.  Your explanation of how to use `action="store_true"` is much better than the documentation's.