# Subparsers.add_parser TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prog'

Tags: python, argparse, python-decorators

I need to implement an ArgParse builder to generate parsers and regarding subparsers and arguments. I created a decorator to declare subparsers as action. Here is the class which contains the decorator:

```
class Controller(object):
    endpoints = None
    parser = None
    subparsers = None

    def __init__(self, endpoint=None):
        from src.app.commons.ArgParser import ArgParser
        if not self.parser:
            self.parser = ArgParser()
        # Get all 
        self.endpoints = utilities.conf_wrapper()
        self.mod = endpoint
        if not self.subparsers:
            self.subparsers = self.parser.add_subparsers(help=gettext('%s_SUBPARSER_HELP' % str(self.mod).upper()))
        self.parser.add_argument_group(self.mod, gettext('%s_GROUP_DESC' % str(self.mod).upper()))


    def endpoint(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        """ Create an endpoint to define a method on behalf of subparser"""
        ref = self
        def decorator(f):
            """
            Create subparser for controller object
            @param f as a function to call
            @return decorator method
            """
            # TODO Set given function f as a subparser destination
            new_sub_parser = ref.subparsers.add_parser(endpoint, help=gettext('%s_%s_HELP' % (ref.mod, endpoint)))
            [new_sub_parser.add_argument("--%s" % arg, action='store') for arg in ref.endpoints[ref.mod][endpoint]["params"]]
            setattr(ConsoleInterface, 'do_%s' % endpoint, f)

        return decorator
```

And here is how I call it inside the class:

```
from src.app.controller import Controller

network = Controller("network")


@network.endpoint('create')
def create(*args):
    try:
        print "I am here"
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

What I am expecting here is create some parsers as command like this:

```
$~ network create [arguments]
```

According to the ArgParse [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) I do everything right, but I got the exception like:

```
  File "/projectpath/src/app/controller/__init__.py", line 48, in decorator
    new_sub_parser = ref.subparsers.add_parser(endpoint, help=gettext('%s_%s_HELP' % (ref.mod, endpoint)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1066, in add_parser
    parser = self._parser_class(**kwargs)
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prog'
```

When I look at the `ArgParse._SubParsersAction.__init()__` it covers 'prog' inside kwargs.

Comment: This might help: https://bugs.python.org/issue23487 also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574270/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-type-in-argparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with `ArgParser()` class.  I don't know what that is, though it may be a customized `argparse.ArgumentParser` (as subclass).

`add_parser` makes sure there is a `prog` in the `kwargs`, which it then passes to `parser = self._parser_class(**kwargs)`. `_parser_class` is the class of the main parser unless an alternative is specified in the `add_subparsers` line.

So I'm guessing that `ArgParser` does not accept a `prog` keyword, even though `ArgumentParser` does.  But I don't think we can help you without knowing more about its source.

Comment: Thanks for inspiration @hpaulj!  I use my own class ArgParse inherited from ArgumentParser and I did not put **kwargs into constructer.     
`class ArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):    

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):    
`    
That is why it happens. I fixed it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem!

I created my class `ArgParser` which extends `argparse.ArgumentParser`, and inside it, I had `self.add_subparsers()` call, which caused this problem.

```py
class ArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    """A class to group all the arg parse stuff.
    You dont need to pay attention here unless you want to edit CLI args spec"""

    def __init__(self):
        p_args = dict(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
        super().__init__(**p_args)
        self.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=f'%(prog)s {__version__}')
        sub_ps = self.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
        sub_ps.required = True
        # ...  and lot other stuff
```

so, that causes `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prog'`

### How to fix?

Explicitly set `parser_class=argparse.ArgumentParser` as in

```py
sub_ps = self.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', parser_class=argparse.ArgumentParser)
```